# Growing abruptly and aggressively - words

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives

How to describe a sudden increasing in size, volume. For example when fires grow suddenly and rapidly. What does that fire do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **it flared up**
- it blazed up
- it suddenly raged (with irresistible fury)
- it started to lick hungrily at (something)
- it suddenly filled the sky with a golden guttering light

Answer (score 4):

There are several different *kinds* of things that can suddenly increase in size/volume - and as Talia's answer indicates, there are many ways of describing just one (fire). Other things (teenage acne spots, for example) might *explode*, or *erupt*.

But a couple of more "general-purpose" verbs are...

> [***balloon***:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/balloon) to swell or puff out (even *fire* can [balloon](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20fire%20ballooned%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1))
>    [***mushroom***:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mushroom?show=0&t=1382834364) to become enlarged or extended (and it can certainly [mushroom](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20fire%20ballooned%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22the%20fire%20mushroomed%22&tbm=bks))

Answer (score 1):

**Exploded**

From page 7 of *[The Thirty Mile Fire](http://books.google.com/books?id=hmkgew1cOa0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22fire%20exploded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=75BsUtHWNs3nkAfFyIHQAQ&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBDg8#v=onepage&q=exploded&f=false)*

> In late afternoon a sudden wind struck a sputtering fire in a narrow
>   canyon on Storm King Mountain in west-central Colorado. The **fire
>   exploded** in a scarlet-orange ball of flame, which raced a fire crew up
>   the canyon and left fourteen of them dead.

[Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=gH8_AAAAYAAJ&q=%22fire%20exploded%22&dq=%22fire%20exploded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EY9sUpGUAafF2AXIzIGQDw&ved=0CFgQ6AEwCTgo) is it used in a report from the *Division of Fire Research, Northern Rocky Mountain Forest and Range Experiment Station*, written in 1951:

[image: Division of Fire Research, Northern Rocky Mountain Forest and Range Experiment Station]

[Here](http://books.google.com/books?id=y2QeAQAAIAAJ&q=%22fire%20exploded%22&dq=%22fire%20exploded%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EY9sUpGUAafF2AXIzIGQDw&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCDgo) is another from the book *Past Lives and Times in the United States Forest Service*, written in 2005:

[image: Past Lives and Times in the United States Forest Service]

[Explode](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explode): to increase rapidly

Answer (score -1):

**Erupt**

Here you will see it used in an article in MarketWatch 23 October 2013
[image]

Comment: ‘Erupt’ means something quite different—it means ‘break out (violently)’. It does not refer to an increase in size or volume. In addition, your examples are all of a _volcano_, in which case ‘erupt’ has an even more specific meaning.